# Kafka connect mirror maker 2.0 how to replicate data between two postgres databases

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to replicate data between two Postgres databases on separate k3s clusters, each on their own machine, in a one-way data flow. I have been struggling to get my topics replicated from server 1 to server 2 and also be able to register my sink connector to write changes made to the database on server 1 to the database on server 2. I was originally seeing an issue with the schema name in the sink connector not being correct, saying that the schema "source" did not exist. Now I am no longer able to even get my mirror connector to work.

This is my current source connector:

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "10.42.0.188",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "<username>",
    "database.password": "<password>",
    "database.dbname": "<dbname>",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.231.103:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "192.168.231.103:9092",
    "schema.include.list": "public",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.231.103:9092",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "table",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields.table.field": "table",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval": "true",
    "topic.prefix": "dbserver1",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "topic.creation.enable": "true",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "1",
    "include.schema.changes": "true"
  }
}
```

This is my current mirror connector:

```
{
  "name":"test_mirror",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
    "name":"test_mirror",
    "source.cluster.alias":"source",
    "topics.regex":"dbserver1.*",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"192.168.231.103:9092",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"192.168.231.61:9092",
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers":"192.168.231.61:9092",
    "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor":"1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
  }
}
```

And this is my current sink connector:

```
{
"name": "metis-sink",
"config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://10.42.0.50:5432/<database>",
        "connection.user": "<username>",
        "connection.password": "<password>",
        "topics.regex": "source.dbserver1.*",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "pk.fields": "Id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
        }
}
```